# How to not ignore maximum version with dyld

Tags: c, macos, versioning, dyld, dynamic-library

I'm attempting to version a shared library under OS X (10.7.5), but I am having trouble getting `dyld` to recognize a maximum compatibility version (minimum versions are okay).  Consider the test code below and the following scenario:

1. Binary linked against library at version 1.0, compatibility version 1.0

   - `binary` works as expected

     - `otool -L binary`: `libdyldtest.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)`
     - `otool -L libdyldtest.dylib`: `libdyldtest.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)`
2. Library is updated and recompiled, moved to version 2.0, compatibility version 1.0

   - `binary` should still work, and does, since compatibility of library is old enough

     - `otool -L binary`: `libdyldtest.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)`
     - `otool -L libdyldtest.dylib`: `libdyldtest.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.0.0)`
3. Library is updated and recompiled to an incompatible version.  Set both version and compatibility version to 3.0.  Binary is not recompiled.

   - `binary` should **stop** working because it wants something compatible with 1.0 but `libdyldtest` is only compatible with 3.0 and later. *Why does this work?*

     - `otool -L binary`: `libdyldtest.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)`
     - `otool -L libdyldtest.dylib`: `libdyldtest.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)`
     - Setting `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES` shows `libdyldtest.3.0.dylib` being loaded

The problem is that 3 above works, and I don't think it should.  Is this expected behavior?  If not, how can I correct this?

*NOTE*: The relevant [dyld source code for 10.7.5](http://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-195.6/src/ImageLoader.cpp) doesn't seem to make use of the `maxVersion` member of the `LibraryInfo` struct, only `minVersion`.  Thus, setting the minimum compatibility version lower works as expected:

- Library set to version 0.9, compatibility 0.0

  - `binary` stops working, as expected.

    - `otool -L binary`: `libdyldtest.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)`
    - `otool -L libdyldtest.dylib`: `libdyldtest.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.9.0)`

      - Running `binary` results in `Reason: Incompatible library version: binary requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libdyldtest.0.9.dylib`, as expected.

Thanks!

---

## Sample code

library.h:

```
#ifndef __LIBRARY_H__
#define __LIBRARY_H__

void functionFromLibrary();

#endif /* __LIBRARY_H__ */
```

library.c:

```
#include "library.h"

#include <stdio.h>

void
functionFromLibrary()
{
    printf("functionFromLibrary()\n");
}
```

binary.c:

```
#include "library.h"

int
main(
    int argc, 
    char *argv[])
{
    functionFromLibrary();
    return (0);
}
```

Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all library binary

MAJOR=1
MINOR=0
COMPAT=1.0
LIBNAME=dyldtest
BINNAME=binary

all: library binary

binary: binary.o
    $(CC) $< -L. -l$(LIBNAME) -o $(BINNAME)

library: library.o
    $(CC) -dynamiclib $< -Wl,-current_version,$(MAJOR).$(MINOR) \
        -Wl,-compatibility_version,$(COMPAT) -Wl,-macosx_version_min,10.6 \
        -Wl,-install_name,lib$(LIBNAME).dylib \
        -o lib$(LIBNAME).$(MAJOR).$(MINOR).dylib
    ln -f -s lib$(LIBNAME).$(MAJOR).$(MINOR).dylib \
        lib$(LIBNAME).$(MAJOR).dylib
    ln -f -s lib$(LIBNAME).$(MAJOR).dylib lib$(LIBNAME).dylib

clean:
    $(RM) *.o lib$(LIBNAME)*.dylib $(BINNAME)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

The version number checks that `dyld` performs are limited to ensuring that the *compatibility* version of the library being loaded is higher than the compatibility version of the library that was used at build time. The *current* version of the library is something that's programmatically accessible, but isn't used by `dyld` when evaluating whether it should load a particular library. You can learn more about these two version numbers by looking at the `-compatibility_version` and `-current_version` sections of the `ld` man page.

You can achieve the effect you're after by making use of the library's install name. You can see this by looking at how `libSystem.dylib` is used:

```
mrowe@angara:~$ ls -lha /usr/lib/libSystem.{,B.}dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    53K Jul  9  2012 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    17B Jul  9  2012 /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib -> libSystem.B.dylib
mrowe@angara:~$ otool -L /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib | head -2
/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
mrowe@angara:~$
```

Note how the install name in the second line of `otool` output points to the version of the dylib whose name is qualified with the version number (in the case B). If Apple were to introduce a backwards-incompatible revision of `libSystem.dylib` they could put it at `/usr/lib/libSystem.C.dylib` and update the symlink at `libSystem.dylib` to point it. Existing programs would still look for `libSystem.B.dylib` since that's the install name that was written in to their `LC_LOAD_DYLIB` load command back when they were linked. Any program that was *newly linked* against `libSystem.dylib` would find `libSystem.C.dylib` and have its install name written in to their `LC_LOAD_DYLIB` load command. Such a program would fail to launch on a system which lacked `libSystem.C.dylib`.

Comment: So a bug was that the `install_name` I was using did not include the major release number. I'm not sure this completely solves the problem though. `binary` is linked against `libdyldtest`, which `otool` will show as `libdyldtest.1.dylib`. When `libdyldtest.2.dylib` with `compatibility_version` 1 is released, unless the symlink from `libdyldtest.1.dylib` is changed, `binary` still uses `libdyldtest.1.dylib` and not `libdyldtest.2.dylib` until it is relinked.  Apple does say "In general, to use a major revision of a library, the client must be linked with the new version," so maybe expected?

Comment: The point is that you'd only bump the number in the filename when you make backwards-incomatible change, not with every new release.

Comment: Then the number in the filename (the `install_name`) is not necessarily the same as the major number from `current_version`. Makes `compatibility_version` seem a bit useless to me.

Comment: Yup, it's not as useful as it could be, and this is partially because it's not functionality that is widely used. You'll see that most of Apple's frameworks and libraries have compatibility versions that never change, and most third-party applications bundle dylibs with the application bundle so have little need for dealing with differing library versions at anything other than build time.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Dynamic Library Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/DynamicLibraries/000-Introduction/Introduction.html) -> "Managing Client Compatibility With Dependent Libraries" -> "Specifying Version Information". You can set the correct compatiblity using major version and naming.